# PhantomJS crashes after phantom.exit() on Linux

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I've tried to build a very simple solution on top of PhantomJS, but somehow it crashes when calling `phantom.exit()`. For example, when running the following code:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.onResourceRequested = function (request) {
    console.log('Request ' + request.url);
    phantom.exit();
};
page.open('http://www.google.com/');
```

crashes with segmentation fault on Ubuntu (12.04.3 LTS) and CentOS (6.4). If I comment out `phantom.exit()` it lists requested URLs, so it basically works as expected. However `phantom.exit()` is something I really need, as I would like to terminate my script in certain cases (eg. attempt to access specific domain). 
I have a feeling that my issue is too obvious, but haven't a clue of what's going on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's [a known issue](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11306), but there's a simple workaround. Still, it's a bug that should be fixed, but for now:

```
setTimeout(function()
{
    phantom.exit(0);
},0);
```

It's silly, but that should do the trick...There's a patch on the github page I linked to, too. There's also some  more details on why this bug is there.
I think the problem lies here:

> Yes, you're right [phantom.exit should terminate PhantomJS without executing any further code.], but each call to m_pages[i]->close(); calls deleteLater() this means that each object will be deleted, but asynchronous... maybe this is the problem.

The asynchronous deletion seems to me to be the likely cause of the bug, because the handler returns after `setTimeout`, and the actual `exit` call is delayed, everything can be deleted when and where it should be. The timeout effectively moves the `exit` call outside of the handler's scope...
I haven't tested it, but if this is the case, than perhaps:

```
var closeFunc = function()
{
    phantom.exit(0);
};
page.onResourceRequested = function (request)
{
    console.log('Request ' + request.url);
    return closeFunc();
};
```

Would work, too. If it does, than you'll just have to use either one of these workarounds, until a reliable patch or the next version is released, and the bug is fixed.

Comment: Thank you @Elias, the second solution crashes as well, but setTimeout works fine. I've googled of course before posting my message here, and have seen similar solutions... but it was discussion from 2012, I would never assume that such critical issue still not fixed after a year!

Comment: It's now 2015, nearing 2016, and I have the same issue :(

Comment: @siliconrockstar: It's actually a really tricky bug to fix. It's something that is inherent to JS's way of handling callbacks: there's one call queue, that is checked intermittently. If you call `phantom.exit(0);` directly, the call queue might not be empty. Using `setTimeout` pushes the `phantom.exit(0)` call to then end of that queue, assuring all pending calls were executed... It's not so much a bug as it is by language-design